# Android: How can i display dates on x- axis in AchartEngine linegraph?

Tags: android

I am implementing an app in which i am facing a problem in displaying dates on x-axis? I am getting x and y vaues from webservice. I am getting dates and price values? Can any one you give an example to implement this?